# How to handle the huge data(>10 million) in sapui5 oTable?

Tags: javascript, pagination, sapui5

I am using sap ui5 oTable for showing the huge data from hana db. While loading the huge data, the browser is going to crash.So I am fetching 100 records from db and showing the 20 records per page.So we can have 5 pagination(5*20=100)  with one manual next button. If I click next manual button, I should get next 100 records and pagination should be 6,7,8,9,10.but i could not change the pagination no.

1. How to change the default pagination number in oTable?
2. How to achieve lazy loading concept in oTable?
3. Normally how to achieve the huge data handling in oTable?

Comment: Are you using oData already?

Comment: Yes. I am using oData.

Comment: more than 1 crore data

Comment: I mean, no-one here knows what "crore" means. Not everyone on this site lives in India.

Comment: @torazaburo one crore means 10 million records. Didn't mean to offend. Just letting you know the number. Mathematically (10,000,000)

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit cryptic

Q: If you are asking, why does the odata call only return 100 rows at a time?

The ODataListBinding which populates the table uses the model size limit, which by default is 100, this number is then used in the OData Query populating the $top and $skip query options

```
eg $top=100 $skip=0
```

returning the first 100 rows only

Q: How do i change the size limit to bring back more than 100 records

```
oModel.setSizeLimit(999999)
```